# Atom git-plus doesn't detect my .gitconfig

Tags: git, atom-editor

I've got `git-plus` Atom plugin installed.

Now, I created a repository with `README`, I've cloned it onto my disk (before I've configured

```
git config --global user.name 
git config --global user.email
```

and `ssh`.

I opened the directory (with `.git` directory in it) in Atom, edited some code, and now I wanted to use `git-plus`' `Add+Commit+Push`.
I clicked that, and I got that error:

[image]

[image]

I've got `HOME` environment variable set to `C:\Users\Frynio`. In `C:\Users\Frynio` I've got `.gitconfig` file and `.ssh` here as well. What am I doing wrong then?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your configuration:

```
git config
```

You can even add the `--show-origin` flag to see where the definition is coming from.
After that check to see that the keys are in place

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

if its still not working after that try

Comment: Sorry for not answering. I checked. It is properly configured and keys are in place (I can push from cmdline). Maybe the issue is I got Git for Windows and cygwin